# Deleting all items in a page one by one in Android recyclerview does not load the next set of data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented recyclerview and it loads 10 tasks at a time. Once every task is completed, I am removing the task with a completed button. It loads the 11th item if I scroll to the bottom at one condition there has to be atleast one uncompleted task present on the page. If I clear all 10 items it just shows me loading animation and nothing happens. I have to close the app and open again to load the tasks again.

I have implemented a PaginationActivity, PaginationAdapter and scroll listener for the page. It loads data from a local database whenever you have reached the end of the page and you have got more tasks to load.

PaginationActivity.java

```
public class PaginationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

PaginationAdapter adapter;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

public static ArrayList<String> reasonsdata = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String rslt="";
public static String[] reasons;
public static boolean chk = true;
public static String payTypeSelected;
public static String reasonSelected;
public static HashMap<String, EditText> drivernotesMap = new HashMap<String, EditText>();
public static HashMap<String, EditText> paynoteMap = new HashMap<String, EditText>();
public static HashMap<String, String> paytypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


RecyclerView rv;
ProgressBar progressBar;

private static final int PAGE_START = 0;
private boolean isLoading = false;
private boolean isLastPage = false;
private int TOTAL_PAGES;
private int currentPage = PAGE_START;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pagination_main);
    fillspinner();

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.main_progress);

    adapter = new PaginationAdapter(this);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    rv.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;

            // mocking network delay for API call
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadNextPage();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public int getTotalPageCount() {
            return TOTAL_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });


    // mocking network delay for API call
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadFirstPage();
        }
    }, 1000);

}

private void fillspinner() {
    reasonsdata.clear();
    try
    {
        rslt="START";
        CallReasons cr = new CallReasons();
        cr.join();
        cr.start();
        while(rslt=="START") {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(rslt == "Success"){
        reasonsdata.add("<--- Select Reason --->");
        for(int i =0; i< reasons.length;i++){
            reasonsdata.add(reasons[i]);
        }
    }
}

public void loadFirstPage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadFirstPage: ");
    TOTAL_PAGES = Run.getTotalPages();
    //List<Run> runs = Run.createRuns(adapter.getItemCount());
    List<Run> runs = Run.createRuns(adapter.getMaxID());
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter.addAll(runs);

    if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
    else isLastPage = true;
}

public void loadNextPage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadNextPage: " + currentPage);
    //List<Run> runs = Run.createRuns(adapter.getItemCount());
    List<Run> runs = Run.createRuns(adapter.getMaxID());

    adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
    isLoading = false;

    adapter.addAll(runs);

    if (currentPage != TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
    else isLastPage = true;
}
```

}

PaginationAdapter.java

```
    public class PaginationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int ITEM = 0;
    private static final int LOADING = 1;

    private List<Run> runs = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;

    private String cash = "CASH";
    private String cheque = "CHEQUE";

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    //PaginationActivity func_call;

    public PaginationAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        runs = new ArrayList<>();
        //func_call = new PaginationActivity();
    }

    public List<Run> getRuns() {
        return runs;
    }

    public void setRuns(List<Run> runs) {
        this.runs = runs;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM:
                viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater);
                break;
            case LOADING:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_progress, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new LoadingVH(v2);
                //viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater);
                //func_call.loadNextPage();
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @NonNull
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new RunVH(v1);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Run run = runs.get(position);

        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case ITEM:
                final RunVH runVH = (RunVH) holder;
                //adding text areas to show data
                //Completed task button
                runVH.btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Mark as Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    remove(run);

                                }

                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            //pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            case LOADING:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return runs == null ? 0 : runs.size();
    }

    //@Override
    public int getMaxID() {
        if(runs == null || runs.size() == 0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            Run test = runs.get(runs.size()-2);
            int maxid = (int) test.getProperty(0);
            return maxid;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == runs.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? LOADING : ITEM;
    }

    public void add(Run run) {
        runs.add(run);
        notifyItemInserted(runs.size() - 1);
    }

    public void addAll(List<Run> runList) {
        for (Run run : runList) {
            add(run);
        }
    }

    public void remove(Run run) {
        int position = runs.indexOf(run);
        if (position > -1) {
            runs.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, runs.size());
        }
        /*if(runs.size() < 0){
            clear();
            func_call.loadNextPage();
        }*/
    }

    public void clear() {
        isLoadingAdded = false;
        while (getItemCount() > 0) {
            remove(getItem(0));
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return getItemCount() == 0;
    }


    public void addLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = true;
        add(new Run());
    }

    public void removeLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = false;

        int position = runs.size() - 1;
        Run item = getItem(position);

        if (item != null) {
            runs.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public Run getItem(int position) {
        return runs.get(position);
    }

    protected class RunVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textEsky;
        private TextView textAdjusted;
        private TextView textAddress;
        private TextView textNew;
        private TextView textTrusted;
        private TextView textName;
        private TextView textMobile;
        private TextView textHome;
        private TextView textWork;
        private TextView payType;
        private EditText textPayNote;
        private EditText textDeliveryInst;
        private EditText textDriverNotes;
        private final Spinner reasons;
        private RadioGroup rg;
        private Button btnSave;
        private CheckBox IsDriverData;

        public RunVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textEsky = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idEsky);
            textAdjusted = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idAdjusted);
            textAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idAddress);
            textNew = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNew);
            textTrusted = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTrusted);
            textName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idName);
            textMobile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idMobile);
            textHome = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idHome);
            textWork = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idWork);
            payType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idPayType);
            textPayNote = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idPayNoteText);
            textDeliveryInst = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idDeliInsText);
            textDriverNotes = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idDriverNotesText);
            IsDriverData = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idCheckBox);
            reasons = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idReason);
            rg = (RadioGroup) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Radiogroup);
            btnSave = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }


    protected class LoadingVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public LoadingVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }


}
```

PaginationScrollListener.java

```
public abstract class PaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    public PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void loadMoreItems();

    public abstract int getTotalPageCount();

    public abstract boolean isLastPage();

    public abstract boolean isLoading();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it looks to me like the only time you call `loadNextPage()` is when the RecyclerView gets a scroll event. Removing ViewHolders doesn't cause scroll events iirc.

If you register an [AdapterDataObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver.html) on the `PaginationAdapter`, you can listen in on removal/add events and trigger loads when there aren't any tasks left. You could probably do the same thing with some small changes to that commented-out code in `remove(Run)`:

```
if (runs.isEmpty()) {
    func_call.loadNextPage();
}
```

EDIT:

Btw, you see where you called `adapter = new PaginationAdapter(this);` in the `PaginationActivity.onCreate` method? The `this` here is your PaginationActivity, which means you can assign it to a `PaginationAdapter` field like so:

```
/**
 * @param context the activity this adapter will appear in
 */
public PaginationAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    runs = new ArrayList<>();
    func_call = (PaginationActivity)context;
}
```

That should be enough to prevent crashes. For better separation of concerns, you'll probably want to switch over to `AdapterDataObserver`-based logic (I think this is called the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)? Maybe?).

Comment: I am confused here. I am still learning android programming. I might be doing rookie mistakes. loadNextPage() is written under PaginationActivity class. I try to call that function by creating an object func_call. But that creates a complete new instance and app crashes. Is there some workaround. <br />public PaginationAdapter(Context context) { this.context = context; runs = new ArrayList<>(); //func_call = new PaginationActivity(); }

Comment: @venutamizh so, the context there _is_ your PaginationActivity. You can cast it, then save it to the func_call field. Context objects are usually one of four things: 1. an Activity, 2. a Service, 3. an Application, 4. a wrapper around one of the other three (with like a different theme or something).